# Can't get Meld 1.1.5 to run correctly on headless RHEL 5.3

Tags: python, git, merge-conflict-resolution, meld, x11-forwarding

I desperately need to be able to run Meld on a headless RHEL 5.3 VM (`ssh -X <hostname>` on Linux or PuTTY + Xming on Windows—I get the exact same error—see below).

I've had no problems with installing Meld using `yum` on  previous versions of RHEL I had, but this is a customized corporate VM and I couldn't get it to retrieve Meld from a repo, no matter how hard I tried, so this is what I ended up doing:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.is.co.za/mirror/ftp.rpmforge.net/redhat/el5/en/i386/dag/RPMS/meld-1.1.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
$ rpm -Uvh meld-1.1.5-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
$ git config --global merge.tool meld
```

I thought that was it, because when I tested the installation using the `meld` command, the program forwards through X11 and runs correctly. However, when I simulate a merge conflict and run `git mergetool`, Meld fails as follows:

```
Normal merge conflict for 'test.txt':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/meld/meld", line 78, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2: undefined symbol: _XEatDataWords
```

This is where I'm stuck. Line 78 of `/usr/share/meld/meld` is just `import gtk`...which is already installed. Line 40 of `__init__.py` is, likewise, `from gtk import _gtk`. The problem seems to be with this line:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2: undefined symbol: _XEatDataWords
```

This seems to be a pretty esoteric error. Has anyone ever seen something similar? Is there maybe a requirement or dependency that I'd missed?